# Finding the distance between 2 maximas of a histogram in python

Tags: python-2.7, histogram

I have histograms with a global maximum (always positive) and a local maximum (always negative). Example see [here](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-23953084/Paper.png.html). I want to find the distance between the 2 maximas in python 2.7.

Same question but for C#: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694523/finding-the-local-maxima-peaks-and-minima-valleys-of-histograms).

For finding the global max: the solution of [Guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18818905/find-the-x-value-corresponding-to-a-histogram-max) helped me.

When I can find the local maxima I can calculate the distance to the global maxima. Can someone help?

Update: I found out how to smooth my histogram from the solution of Justin Peel: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150171/how-to-create-a-density-plot-in-matplotlib)

Now I have this [function](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-23973694/figure_1.png.html) and I want to calculate the distance between the maxima.

Comment: What distance metric are you using; what doesn't work with your current approach?

Comment: my current idea is to use a sliding window in order to calculate all local maxima. I think that this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with a sliding window. It checks if the middle element of the windows is the max:
if yes: append the solution to maxima-array.
if not the window will shift one element to the right.

To avoid very small maxima, I put a condition that it should be at least a certain level.

Thank you.